# How to make svn automatically detect delete's and move's of the file (shell, Ubuntu)

Tags: svn, shell, ubuntu

Вeing a happy user of git I now have to switch back to svn in one of the projects. I use it through the shell in Ubuntu and look for some command which may be similar to "git add ." - looking for all the files and folders being added, deleted or moved and making appropriate changes in the repository.

Does it exist? It seems so strange to me that you have to tell it svn explicitly every time you want to delete or move something..

Your tips will save my time, thanks! :)

Comment: The problem was not resolved and we switched to git inside the team which makes me really happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `svn rm $( svn status | sed -e '/^!/!d' -e 's/^!//' )`

See http://geryit.com/blog/2011/03/command-line-subversion-practices/ for more command line subversion

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if this is what you are looking for, but

```
svn add * --force
```

will add all files in subdirectories.

Comment: Will it delete from the repository those files which were deleted in file system? Is it the same as svn add * ?

Comment: sorry, typo. i don't think it will delete, no.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make use of [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=why&lang=en) or [inotifywait](http://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki) to take action upon changes in selected portions of your filesystem.